# REST API response to URL rewriting

Tags: php, .htaccess, rest, curl, pdo

I am trying REST API USING PHP. I have modified my URL REWRITING using .htaccess rules. [This](http://localhost/API2/products.php)  is the POST URL which is sent from my curl code along with DATA ARRAY. So that php reads its as a POST COMMAND AND INSERTS the data into my products table using PDO.

this is my code for curl command:

```
       <?php
    $data=array(
    'product_name' =>'Television',
    'price' => 1000,
    'quantity' => 10,
    'seller' =>'XYZ Traders'
  );
  $url = 'http://localhost/API2/products';
  $ch = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  $response_json = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  $response=json_decode($response_json, true);
  echo $response;
 ?>
```

While my php code for products.php is:

```
      <?php
 // Connect to database
require_once('database.php');
$request_method=$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];

switch($request_method)
{
   case 'POST':
        // Insert Product
        insert_product($db);
        break;
   default:
        // Invalid Request Method
        header("HTTP/1.0 405 Method Not Allowed");
        break;
 }
 function insert_product($db)
{
    //global $connection;

    $_product_name=$_POST["product_name"];
    $_price=$_POST["price"];
    $_quantity=$_POST["quantity"];
    $_seller=$_POST["seller"];

    $query = 'INSERT INTO products
             (Product_name, Price, Quantity,Seller)
          VALUES
             ( :product_name, :price, :quantity,:seller)';
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
//$statement->bindValue(':category_id', $category_id);
$statement->bindValue(':product_name', $_product_name);
$statement->bindValue(':price', $_price);
$statement->bindValue(':quantity', $_quantity);
$statement->bindValue(':seller', $_seller);
$bool=$statement->execute();
$statement->closeCursor();

    if($bool)
    {
        $response=array(
            'status' => 1,
            'status_message' =>'Product Added Successfully.'
        );
    }
    else
    {
        $response=array(
            'status' => 0,
            'status_message' =>'Product Addition Failed.'
        );
    }
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($response);
}

//$db = null;
// Close database connection
//mysqli_close($connection);
```

when i send the request to my localhost it recieves it but no response is being sent. Products is a table with product_ID,Product_name,Price,Quantity,Seller. So how to make it work. I am trying to develop REST API using all its rules so don't know whats the issue.